# Ruby - get all elements in array1 that are in array2

Tags: ruby, arrays

```
a1 = [1, 2, 2, 1, 4]
a2 = [1, 2, 3]
```

Expected output:

```
[1, 2, 2, 1]
```

These are the four elements in a1 that are in a2.

`a1 & a2` gives me only uniq elements `[1, 2]` but i need non-uniq elements.

Is there a better way than doing the following, which i think is not efficient:

```
a1.select{|ele| a2.include?(ele)}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a1 - (a1 - a2)
# => [1, 2, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add my ¢2. If you are likely to make an operation a few times on huge arrays, @sawa’s method is definitely your choice:

```
require 'benchmark'

n = 1_000
a1 = 1_000.times.map { rand(1..100) }
a2 = 1_000.times.map { rand(5..95) }
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report {
    n.times do
      a1 - (a1 - a2) 
    end
  }
  x.report {
    n.times do
      a1.keep_if { |xx| a2.include? xx }
    end
  }
end
```

results in:

```
#     user     system      total        real
# 0.340000   0.000000   0.340000 (  0.424604)
# 5.590000   0.010000   5.600000 (  6.438095)
```

But if there are lots of subtractions on small arrays:

```
- n = 1_000
- a1 = 1_000.times.map { rand(1..100) }
- a2 = 1_000.times.map { rand(5..95) }
+ n = 100_000
+ a1 = 10.times.map { rand(1..100) }
+ a2 = 10.times.map { rand(5..95) }
```

the opposite looks more appropriate:

```
#     user     system      total        real
# 0.550000   0.010000   0.560000 (  0.551997)
# 0.150000   0.000000   0.150000 (  0.151695)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an option

```
a1.keep_if { |x| a2.include? x }
```